# Search on listview (activity extends ListActivity)

Tags: android, listview, filter

i extend `ListActivity` and bind `ListView` in my activity. applied filter to listview. the filter is working fine when use emulater, because i have keyboard of my laptop. but the problem arises when i want to filter data on android because it does not display keyboard to me. code is give below.

```
String[] Customers = {"Alester","Lee","Broad","James"};
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, Customers));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hmmm, try to add some key listener and then when there is event show up the keyboard.

Comment: Better is to put an `EditText` on the top of `ListView`

Answer (score 3):

Put an EditText somewhere, like on top of your listView, then add a TextWatcher like :

```
    TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            _myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    };
    _filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    _filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Zoleas: dont have a ui for the activity. when i extent ListActivity it automatically sets the ui of the screen. and i dont have any edit text for the activity so how can i filter the text.....

Comment: From the doc : ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"

Comment: So you can do your own layout with an EditText for example. Or you can either implement the search feature : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html