# Search on ListView when the class extends ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

When I want to search on a ListView and the class extends Activity or AppCompatActivity I'm using this below codes and it works correctly.

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

But when the class extends ListActivity and I'm using the codes, it's not working.I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121422/5790367), but it's not working too.

How can I search on a ListView when the class extends ListActivity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How can I search on a ListView when the class extends ListActivity?* in the same way ... please define: *it's not working*

Comment: @Selvin: I mean it's not searching on ListView.